# Mvx.Resolve fails in unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin, mocking, nunit, mvvmcross

I'm currently trying to write unit tests for an android/ios application written in xamaring using mvvmcross. I've followed the instructions in the [wiki](https://mvvmcross.com/docs/testing) and they do work well to the point when a service tries to change the ViewModel this way:

```cs
var viewDispatcher = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewDispatcher>();
viewDispatcher?.ShowViewModel(
new MvxViewModelRequest(typeof(HomeViewModel), null, null, MvxRequestedBy.Unknown));
```

The tests fail at the first line with `Mvx.Resolve();`. I assume this is down to registering the interfaces in the mock IoC container:

```cs
this.mockDispatcher = new MockDispatcher();
this.Ioc.RegisterSingleton<IMvxViewDispatcher>(this.mockDispatcher);
this.Ioc.RegisterSingleton<IMvxMainThreadDispatcher(this.mockDispatcher);
```

so Mvx cannot resolve then when called this way. Can this code be tested or is there any other possibility to change the ViewModel from the service?

Answer (score 6):

I think your `AdditionalSetup` never gets called. You have to add the `SetUp` attribute to a setup method and call the `Setup()` of `MvxIoCSupportingTest` if you use nunit, else the respective attribute.

```cs
public abstract class MvxTestBase : MvxIoCSupportingTest
{
    protected MockDispatcher mockDispatcher;

    protected override void AdditionalSetup()
    {
        this.mockDispatcher = new MockDispatcher();
        this.Ioc.RegisterSingleton<IMvxViewDispatcher>(this.mockDispatcher);
        this.Ioc.RegisterSingleton<IMvxMainThreadDispatcher>(this.mockDispatcher);
    }

    [SetUp]
    public virtual void SetupTest()
    {
        Setup();
    }
}
```

Or you call it in each test as shown here: https://mvvmcross.com/docs/testing#section-test-class-declaration-and-setup

Comment: Dead link, probably equivalent: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/testing/testing/testing.html